# Custom Data Labels in Access Graph

Tags: ms-access, graph, scatter

In Excel, you make an XY (scatter) graph with two columns of numbers: the X and the Y.

If you want to label the points with the values in a third column (such as flavors of ice cream, as shown here: https://www.datasciencemadesimple.com/add-custom-labels-x-y-scatter-plot-excel), you can go to Chart Elements --> Data Labels --> More Options --> Value from Cells.

You can also make a scatter graph in Access; it's a little more complicated: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_access-mso_win10-mso_o365b/how-to-create-a-x-y-scatter-plot-in-access-2016/eaf3e529-7f9b-4a3a-b1c0-61b8b98c86ae.

But now I want the same custom data labels. If there's a way to set them, I can't find it.

Is there a way to customize the data labels in an Access chart?

Comment: Are you using ModernCharts or classic MSGraph? AFAIK, no. Labels are derived from plotted data.

Comment: @June7 I'm using classic MSGraph. Near as I can tell, ModernCharts doesn't have an XY Scatter option - am I wrong?

Comment: Have to trust you on that. I am still in Access2010 and don't have ModernCharts. Done a bunch of charting with MSGraph. Maybe XYScatter is not best chart option, I would think a bar or line would be better for the Stores example. What is your data?

Comment: @june7 My data is a map of cities. The first column is their names, and the other two columns are the X and Y coordinates . In Excel i can have each city name appear next to its dot as a data label.

Comment: What do you mean by x and y - lat and long? Sorry, Access MSGraph cannot do everything Excel graph can and I suppose there are specialized charting apps that can do more than Excel.

Comment: @June7 This is a fictitious map, but you could think of X and Y as Lat and Long. (The reason I'm making it Excel or Access is that I may want to move the cities around.)